# Back-and-Forth Argument vs. "One-Way" Argument

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, alternative-proof

The wikipedia article on the [Back and Forth Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) claims at the end:

> If we iterated only step $(1)$, rather than going back and forth, then in some cases the resulting function from A to B would fail to be surjective. In the **easy case of unbounded dense totally ordered sets** it is possible to avoid step $2$ by choosing the element $b_j$ more carefully (by choosing $j$ as small as possible), but this does not work for more complicated examples such as atomless Boolean algebras where steps $1$ and $2$ are both needed.

The emphasis is my own. This "easy case" is exactly the same thing stipulated in the suppositions:

> - $(A, ≤_A)$ and $(B, ≤_B)$ are linearly ordered sets;
> - They are both unbounded, in other words neither A nor B has either a maximum or a minimum;
> - They are densely ordered, i.e. between any two members there is another;
> - They are countably infinite.

I haven't learnt anything about atomless boolean algebras. So can someone explain why the latter method cannot be applied to them?

More info: Silver, Charles L. ["Who invented Cantor's back-and-forth argument?"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rml/1204835164)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first explain why the argument using only step 1 *does* work for dense linear orders.  Given two countable dense linear orders $A=\{a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_n\}$, we define $f:A\to B$ as follows.  Having defined $f(a_0),\dots,f(a_{n-1})$, the rest of the set $B$ is divided into $n+1$ intervals by comparing with these elements $f(a_0),\dots,f(a_{n-1})$.  The set $A$ is also split into $n+1$ intervals, by comparing with the elements $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$.  The element $a_n$ lies in one of these intervals in $A$, which corresponds to one of the intervals in $B$.  We define $f(a_n)$ to be $b_j$ for the least $b_j$ that is in that corresponding interval of $B$.

Now, why is this surjective?  Well, we clearly have $f(a_0)=b_0$.  Now say $b_1>b_0$.  Then as soon as we reach an element of $A$ which is greater than $a_0$, that element will map to $b_1$.  Now say $b_0<b_2<b_1$.  As soon as we reach an element of $A$ which is between $a_0$ and $f^{-1}(b_1)$, that element will map to $b_2$.  And so on.  Once we have already found that $b_0,\dots,b_{j-1}$ are in the image of $f$, $b_j$ is in one of the intervals determined by the values of $f$ defined so far.  Eventually we must find some element of $A$ which is in the corresponding interval of $A$ (since $A$ is dense), and that element will map to $b_j$.

The key thing that makes this work is that the condition which guarantees an element of $A$ will map to $b_j$ doesn't change.  We have an entire interval in $A$ which will map to $b_j$ as soon as we pick an element of that interval.  And even if we define $f$ on other values in the meantime, the interval that needs to map to $b_j$ doesn't change.  When you define a new value $f(a_n)$, that only splits up one of the intervals of $A$ (namely the one that $a_n$ was in), and the rest don't change.

When you make the analogous argument for atomless Boolean algebras, however, the condition for an element of $A$ to map to any particular $b_j$ is constantly changing.  That is, with each new value $f(a_n)$ which we define, *every* "interval" of $A$ determined by the values we have defined so far gets split up.  This means that we might go through the entire process of defining $f$ without ever picking an element of $A$ which is in the correct "interval" for $b_j$, since that correct "interval" shrinks at every step.  As a result, the version of the argument using only step 1 won't work for atomless Boolean algebras, since you can't guarantee that $f$ will be surjective.

[Explicitly, the elements $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ split a Boolean algebra $A$ into "intervals" as follows.  Given an element $x\in A$, consider the set $S$ of elements $s$ of the subalgebra generated by $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ such that $x\geq s$ and the set $T$ of $t$ such that $x\leq t$.  We then partition $A$ into pieces, where in each piece the values of these sets $S$ and $T$ are fixed: these are what I referred to as the "intervals".]

Comment: What is the difference between the four conditions and "dense linear orders" that makes atomless Boolean algebras satisfy the former but not latter?

Comment: It seems someone has edited the wikipedia page. When I first posted the question here, the page said that the back-and-forth (step 1 & 2) is necessary for the 4 conditions and they give "atomless boolean algebra" as an example but to me those four conditions are equivalent to saying "unbounded countable dense linear orders" for which the same paragraph said step 1 was sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the four conditions".  If you mean the four conditions you listed in the second quote of your question, those four conditions are the hypotheses to apply the back-and-forth argument to a pair of dense linear orders.  They aren't the general hypotheses involved in making any back-and-forth argument at all, and in particular are totally irrelevant to the case of atomless Boolean algebras.

Comment: The corresponding statement for atomless Boolean algebras is "if $A$ and $B$ are countable atomless Boolean algebras, then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic".  The proof is formally very similar to the proof for dense linear orderings, using analogues of the steps 1 and 2, but the details of exactly what you do in each step are different.  One notable difference that results is that for dense linear orderings you can skip step 2 and still get a working proof (with a little more work), but with atomless Boolean algebras you can't, for the reasons I sketched in my answer.

Comment: You said you didn't know anything about atomless Boolean algebras, so I tried to describe how the argument differs for them (and why skipping step 2 won't work) in broad, qualitative terms.  To completely understand it you would need to actually learn the basic theory of Boolean algebras and read how the full proof goes for atomless Boolean algebras.

Comment: Yeah, when I posted the question I thought the 4 conditions were the most general for the argument and that's where my confusion stemmed from. But I get it now, thanks for the clarification!